# facebook connect for iPhone session expiring

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, graph, facebook

I am using Graph Api for fb connect in iphone, it works fine on one page when I login through the API methods but when I switched my view on I lost the session How to get my current session on next page?

Thanks
Mani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
In new graph api there is no function [_session resume]; exist. That is a function from old rest api.
In my case I just stored that _facebook facebook class object in my delegate object so its available to me on all views.